# How to make pagination with UITableView along with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pagination, uisegmentedcontrol

My view controller has a UISegmentedControl with 6 buttons/segment. It also has a UITableView under that Segmented Control. If we switch segment by click then table view is reloading with different data. Now we are trying to implement a way where if user swipe the table view either in left-to-right or right-to-left, a pagination like behaviour will be appeared in the view controller.

Means the table view will horizontally scrolled along with segmented control. How can we implement this feature in my app in best approach ? My table has three different custom cell, one of which also has a UICollectionView inside the cell.

Comment: I suppose it should be table view within collection view, so you can make collection views scroll horizontally and enable pagination in them, which will also make your work easier with UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea I would suggest is to use `tableView` inside `collectionView`. Steps to follow-:

1) Add `segmentedControl` and `collectionView` on your controller.

2) Connect `dataSource` and `delegate` by control dragging from `collectionView` to controller *yello* icon.

3) Adjust your `cell` height.

4) Select `collectionView`, and go to *attribute inspector*. Look for-: 1) ***scroll direction*** and make *horizontal*. 2) Check `Paging Enabled` parameter.

5) Apply `Constraints` on `views`.

6) Give `collectionView` cell identifier.

7) Give your `cell` a custom `collectionView` cell class.

8) Connect all `Outlets` to respected `views`.

**Controller class -:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var controls: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    // ARRAy OF TYPE UICOLOR
    var collectionViewColors = [UIColor.gray,UIColor.green,UIColor.red,UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.brown]

    // ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    //didReceiveMemoryWarning
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // Function to calculate cell index on scroll end.
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
        let pagingIndex = targetContentOffset.pointee.x/self.view.frame.width
        // Set segmented controll current index
        controls.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(pagingIndex)
    }

}

// Collection view methods

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    // number of section
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // number of items in section
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionViewColors.count
    }
    // deque cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection", for: indexPath) as! HorizontalCell
        cell.horizonatlColorsView.backgroundColor = collectionViewColors[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    // set minimum line spacing to zero.
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

**Custom cell class-:**

```
import UIKit

    class HorizontalCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        // UIView outlet
        @IBOutlet weak var horizonatlColorsView: UIView!
    }
```

After setting up everything , scroll horizontally you will get the output you want.Also you can add `tableView` inside `collectionView` now.

Output-:

[image]

[image]